# How to add validation/restrictions for HTML5 date field

Tags: javascript, html

```
<form>
<input type="date" name="bday" id="bday" required />
</form>
```

i'm trying to add an age restrict to at least 13 years old
i heard about attr max to add it to the input 
https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html

can anyone help me validation using max or javascript

Comment: Do you want to just check if the person is at least 13 years old or do you want to prevent anybody from entering a date that is 13 years less than current date?

Comment: You could calculate the date in javascript and then add it to the `min` attribute by getting the id of the input.

Comment: yes i want to prevent a value less than 13 years old to the current date

Comment: you can use the `min` attribute on range-ish inputs.

Comment: @dandavis can you give me any example 
i don't know how to add a date - 13 years to min